# Group theory and Complex Analysis

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Actually this time I am having interest in group Theory and complex analysis. So I want to study the topics which relate both. So please suggest me which topic or book should I read to explore the relationship between these two thing.

Comment: Mobius transformations!

Answer (score 1):

One such topic is the automorphism groups of complex domains. You could try the following survey to get you started:

> Isaev, Alexander V., and Steven G. Krantz. "Domains with non-compact automorphism group: a survey." Advances in mathematics 146.1 (1999): 1-38.

Another example is

> Bedford, Eric, and Jiri Dadok. "Bounded domains with prescribed group of automorphisms." Commentarii Mathematici Helvetici 62.1 (1987): 561-572.

which has both a complex analytic and (Lie) group-theoretic flavour. You could also try searching "automorphism group of X" where X is your favourite complex-analytic object.